# Link private repositories to private projects

Tags: git, github, github-projects

Is it possible to link private repositories to a private project? All collaborators of the private repo's are also members of the project.

I know it's possible to add a project to a private repository. But what if multiple repositories are part of the same project (and is that possible on github?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible in the Project settings:

```
https://github.com/users/{username}/projects/{projectId}/settings/linked_repositories
```

Projects list:
[image: Projects list]

Project settings:
[image: Project settings]

Comment: Yes, thats what I tried. But it was not possible.
But I just found the reason why: Its only possible to link repositories there, that activated "Issues" in its options. If this is not checked, github wont show them in the linkable repos list.
I did not check the option first, because the repo was a legacy repo wich was only there for reference. There would and will be no new Issues there.